# Procedure turn/hold required on this approach?

Tags: instrument-procedures

I am an instrument student nearing my checkride. I recently flew the VOR-A approach into KLOL as a practice approach, using ROBUD as the IAF. I was wondering if the charted hold at MOBOH is required by this procedure?

[image: VOR-A KLOL]

I had a few thoughts:

- It seems like AIM 5-4-9 (a) would say yes, since there is no "PT NA" on the plate. Flying a real IFR flight in this case, it seems likely that ATC would clear for a straight-in approach, in which case the hold would not be necessary.
- If I was flying this approach on a real IFR flight and didn't hear "cleared for the straight in approach", I would ask ATC to clarify.

HOWEVER, I'm curious if, in the absence of specifically being cleared for a straight in approach, I would be expected to fly a circuit in the holding pattern on this approach starting from ROBUD, even though I'm already inbound on the final approach course?

Comment: Hello bencpeters, welcome to aviation.stackexchange.com.

Comment: [Closely related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/23341/62), maybe a dupe?

Comment: @Pondlife I read that one; the difference here is that there's no "No PT" annotation on this chart.

Comment: @Pondlife That other question also includes a OEI scenario.

Answer (score 7):

If you start the procedure at ROBUD and your clearance does not include "cleared for straight in approach", then you are expected to do a procedure turn in the hold. In real life the first thing to do in such situation would be to query the controller "confirm we are cleared for straight in approach", they are very likely to forget it also.

In my opinion, this is an example of an error on the FAA chart, which is missing noPT annotation on the leg from ROBUD to MOFTE. That annotation is present on a Jepp chart. I've seen these kind of errors in the past and FAA is usually pretty good in correcting them, so go ahead and ask them at [Aeronautical Inquires](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/aero_data/Aeronautical_Inquiries/).

[image: VOR-A LOL (Jepp0].

Answer (score -1):

The hold is part of the missed approach. Navigation to the approach would be done via GPS, ATC vectors or via VHF to the vortac. If arriving from the North you would simply intercept the R-153 and track inbound. If arriving from the south, you could go via the vortac, go outbound on the r-333 and commence a procedure turn to the NE at MOBOH/10DME. The “Procedure NA” applies to ROBUD.

Comment: Hi Ben. This is wrong, unless clarified with references. A hold that is only for missed approaches would be a **dotted line** on FAA charts. The thick line is for a hold-in-lieu-of-PT, which in this instance also matches the missed approach.